# Confirm on special value in dropdown

Tags: javascript

If the user changes a drop down it fires a javascript which calls a specific url.

This should only happen when the NEW selected value is not the same like pre-selected before (this works so far).

But if the option value (not the value itself) is "0" then a confirm should appears asking for "do you really want to call the url".

Is this only possible with an external function or inside the onchange?

```
<select onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">
<option value="index.php?include=program&id=93&amp">0</option>
<option value="index.php?include=program&id=23&amp">1</option>
<option value="index.php?include=program&id=87&amp">2</option>
<option value="index.php?include=program&id=55&amp">3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just make an external function? It would be a lot easier to read. That said, it doesn't necessarily *need* to be, and it could be added to the inline onchange handler.

```html
<select onchange="if(this.selectedIndex==0){ if(confirm('Are you sure?')){ console.log(this.value); } } else { console.log(this.value); }">
  <option value="index.php?include=program&id=93&amp">0</option>
  <option value="index.php?include=program&id=23&amp">1</option>
  <option value="index.php?include=program&id=87&amp">2</option>
  <option value="index.php?include=program&id=55&amp">3</option>
</select>
```

The above code checks the index of the selected value, and if it's 0 (the first item), runs the confirm, otherwise runs the standard result. Note I replaced the `window.location.href` with `console.log()` in this example so you can see it working in the snippet. I usually don't like putting things that have any sort of conditions in the inline handlers though, as they're much harder to maintain. You could just put the same thing in a function and place that function in your main `.js` file.

```
<select onchange="changeLocationOnSelect(this,event);">
  <option value="index.php?include=program&id=93&amp">0</option>
  <option value="index.php?include=program&id=23&amp">1</option>
  <option value="index.php?include=program&id=87&amp">2</option>
  <option value="index.php?include=program&id=55&amp">3</option>
</select>

<script>
  function changeLocationOnSelect(el,e){
    if( el.selectedIndex == 0 ){
      if( confirm( 'Are you sure?' ) ){
        console.log(el.value);
      }
    } else {
      console.log(el.value);
    }
  }
</script>
```